# yii2 grid filter type not working

Tags: php, filter, yii2, grid, kartik-v

I am using kartik grid lib in yii2

1. This works.

   ```
   [
   'attribute' => 'status',
   'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
   'filter' => ['Active' => 'Active', 'In Active' => 'In Active'],
   'filterWidgetOptions' => [
       'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
   ],
   'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Select'],
   ]
   ```
2. But this doesn't

   ```
   [
   'attribute' => 'status',
   'filterType' => '\kartik\widgets\Select2',
   'filter' =>['Active' => 'Active', 'In Active' => 'In Active'],
   'filterWidgetOptions' => [
       'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
   ],
   'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Select'],
   ]
   ```

Why ? I need to use the point 2 approach. But it is not working.

Comment: Are you sure `'filterType'` value is the only difference between these two? It should work...

Comment: yes, thats the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

Changed filter type to '\kartik\select2\Select2' and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

usa 'filterType' =>**GridView::FILTER_SELECT2**, el composer usado es **use kartik\grid\GridView;**

```
   'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
   'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Entidad::find()->asArray()->all(),'id', 'nombre'),
    filterWidgetOptions' => [
           'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
    ],
    'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Selección'],
```